# Printing subsets that sum to a target in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime

I am trying to implement an algorithm that prints subsets of an array that sums to a target in C++. I got the algorithm from the internet and implemented it in C++. Can somebody please find out why I am not able to print the complete output? Also in terms of complexity, I think this algorithm is O(2^N). Is there any other better complexity algorithm for this?

This my code :

```
void printSubsets_sumto_target(vector<int> a,int k,vector<int> partial)
{
    int s =0;
    int i,j;
    int psize = partial.size();
    int osize = a.size();
    vector<int> remaining;
    vector<int> partial_rec;

    for(i=0;i<psize;i++)
        s+=partial[i];
    //cout<<"Sum : "<<s<<endl;
    if(s==k)
    {
        //cout<<"Partial size : "<<psize<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<psize;i++)
            cout<<partial[i]<<", ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    if(s>=k)
        return;
    for(i=0;i<osize;i++)
    {
        remaining.empty();
        int n = a[i];
        for(j=i+1;j<osize;j++)
            remaining.push_back(a[j]);
        partial_rec.empty();
        partial_rec.push_back(n);
        printSubsets_sumto_target(remaining,k,partial_rec);
    }
}
```

for this algorithm and a vector a={1,2,3,8,9,7} I am calling with

```
vector<int> partial;
printSubsets_sumto_target(a,10,partial);
```

The output I get is

```
3, 7, 
2, 8, 
3, 7, 
3, 7, 
2, 8,
```

The expected output is

```
1,9
2,8
3,7
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Subset sum is NP Complete. The best known algorithm is O(2^(N/2)). You can find a description on Wikipedia.

Comment: @DeadMG You cannot call O(2^(N/2)) algorithm as best because there exist a pseudo polynomial time algorithm which is O(M*N) where M is target number and N is set size which very efficient if M is small enough even though N is large.

Answer (score 1):

1 . it is a NP problem（but sort the values can cut lots of combinations）

2 . as mentioned , the subset can contain 3 or more elements, so the output can be 7 2 1

3 . I used to write the code for practice , hope it will help

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[100]={1,2,3,8,9,7};
bool x[100];
int N=6;//number of elements
int t=10;//target sum
int sum;//current target sum
int cmp(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    return *(int *)b-*(int *)a;
}
void backtrace(int n)
{
    if(sum>t)
        return ;
    if(sum==t)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            if(x[j])
                cout<<a[j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if(n==N)
        return ;
    for(int i=n;i<N;++i)
    {
        if(x[i]==false)
        {
            x[i]=true;
            sum+=a[i];
            backtrace(i+1);
            x[i]=false;
            sum-=a[i];
            while(i<N-1 && a[i]==a[i+1])
                i++;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    sum=0;
    memset(x,0,sizeof(x));
    qsort(a,N,sizeof(a[0]),cmp);
    backtrace(0);
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs:

9 1

8 2

7 3

7 2 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that has time complexity `O(M*N)` whereas `M` is Target and `N` is total size of set. Use analogy with knapsack problem as follows :-

> 1. Knapsack capacity = Target
> 2. Items are elements in the set with weight & value same as itself
> 3. Calculate maximum profit using dynamic programming
> 4. maxprofit = Target then there is/are subset which sum up to target.
> 5. Retrace the solution.

Java Solution for the same :-

```
public class SubSetSum {
    static int[][] costs;

    public static void calSets(int target,int[] arr) {

        costs = new int[arr.length][target+1];
        for(int j=0;j<=target;j++) {
            if(arr[0]<=j) {

                costs[0][j] = arr[0]; 
            }
        }
        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {

            for(int j=0;j<=target;j++) {
                costs[i][j] = costs[i-1][j];
                if(arr[i]<=j) {
                    costs[i][j] = Math.max(costs[i][j],costs[i-1][j-arr[i]]+arr[i]);
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(costs[arr.length-1][target]);
       if(costs[arr.length-1][target]==target) {
           System.out.println("Sets :");
           printSets(arr,arr.length-1,target,"");
       } 

       else System.out.println("No such Set found");

    } 

    public static void printSets(int[] arr,int n,int w,String result) {


        if(w==0) {
            System.out.println(result);
            return;
        }

        if(n==0) {
           System.out.println(result+","+arr[0]);
            return; 
        }

        if(costs[n-1][w]==costs[n][w]) {
            printSets(arr,n-1,w,new String(result));
        }
        if(arr[n]<=w&&(costs[n-1][w-arr[n]]+arr[n])==costs[n][w]) {
            printSets(arr,n-1,w-arr[n],result+","+arr[n]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,8,9,7};
        calSets(10,arr);
    }
}
```